# Radio button is not selected inside ListView.builder in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Im trying to have groups of radio buttons so I can select one at a time from that group.

**The list of radio buttons which I group to a ListView**

```
ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        controller: _controller,
                        itemCount: _rampValues.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                          var tt = _rampValues[index];
                          return ListTile(
                            title: Text(tt.name!, style: tBody5),
                            leading: Radio(
                                value: tt.selected!,
                                groupValue: _rampResult,
                                onChanged: (value) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _rampResult = value.toString();
                                  });
                                }),
                          );
})
```

The model is like

```
List<ValueModel> _rampValues = [];

var _rampResult;
...

class ValueModel {
  final int? id;
  final int? subId;
  final String? name;
  final String? subName;
  bool? selected;
  bool? subSelected;

  ValueModel(
      {this.id,
      this.subId,
      this.name,
      this.subName,
      this.selected,
      this.subSelected});
}
```

but when I load the UI to view its not selecting nor responding

how can I fix this ?

Comment: Can you include full widget

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Radio` widget should be of type `ValueModel` along with Radio `value` property, like this:

```
ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            controller: _controller,
            itemCount: _rampValues.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
              var tt = _rampValues[index];
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(tt.name!),
                leading: Radio<ValueModel>(
                    value: tt,
                    groupValue: _rampResult,
                    onChanged: (ValueModel? value) {
                      setState(() {
                        _rampResult = value;
                      });
                    }),
              );
            }),
```

Comment: perfect approach. and also I moved the setState out of the onChanged and this works well now. thank you Ante

Comment: how can I set a value to a radio button before user taps a one?

Comment: You can assign default value to your `_rampResult` variable like `late var _rampResult = _rampValues[0];` to preselect one of your `_rampValues` (in this example it's the first value)

Comment: I did this in initState so I can test with 
```_rampResult = ValueModel(
      id: 2,
      subId: 1,
      name: "Anti-Slip",
      subName: "Ramp",
      selected: true,
      subSelected: false,
    );```             but it doesn't update the ui

Comment: That `ValueModel` although it maybe has the same argument values as one of your list items is not the same object, it's a new instance. You have to assign one of your list item values to your `_rampResult` variable like in my previous comment.

Comment: got it. I'll do dat

Answer (score 1):

When you call `setState`

```
setState(() {
   _rampResult = value.toString();
});
```

you change the state and `build` gets triggered again, but your radio buttons are still set to only check the `selected` field:

```
value: tt.selected!,
```

But that field did not change. So your radio buttons do not change. Either you need a logic to change your `selected` fields inside your `setState` or maybe your initial value should be something that is compared to `_rampResult` to find out if it's selected, instead of using a field.